# How can I change the line width of the outline for polygons in the Mapfile?

Tags: mapserver

I display Polygons in the UMN Mapserver. With the `OUTLINE`-keyword I set a color for the outline of the polygons. How can I change the line width of this outline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **OUTLINECOLOR**

Example

```
STYLE # solid fill
  COLOR 255 0 0
END
STYLE # thick outline (could use a circle symbol with size too)
  OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
  WIDTH 3
  ANTIALIAS TRUE
END
```

How do I have a polygon that has both a fill and an outline with a width?
http://mapserver.org/faq.html

Comment: Your answer helped, thanks. But please format the code-example (marking the example and click on the symbol with ones and zeros) for better readability. I didn't understood it at first.

Comment: done - formatting

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the answer above works, but I think that the FAQ is a little out of date.  For reference, below is an example that works for me on a recent version of MapServer.

```
LAYER
  NAME "watersheds"
  STATUS DEFAULT
  DATA 'majclip'
  TYPE POLYGON
    CLASS
       NAME "all_watersheds"
       STYLE
          COLOR "#EEE8AA"
          OUTLINECOLOR "#999999"
          WIDTH .5
       END
    END

END
```